# AngularJS $resource

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

The concept here what I am doing is, sending the post request to the other domain for retrieving the details by using $resource...

I got struck by using $resource..please see the below error..

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://exampledomian.com/api/getCountries/123web/0/0/0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:/localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

factory.js

```
var factories = angular.module('AngularApp.factories',[]);

factories.factory("ApiListFactory", ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return   $resource('http://exampledomian.com/api/getCountries/:ain/:rtmp/:aacp/:mms',
            {ain:'123web', rtmp :0,aacp:0,mms:0},{req:{method:'POST'
                }});
}]);

enter code here
```

Controller.js

```
var AngularApp = angular.module('AngularApp',
        ['ngRoute','ngResource','AngularApp.factories']);

AngularApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
 });

AngularApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
//Enable cross domain calls
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

//Remove the header used to identify ajax call  that would prevent CORS from working
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
});

AngularApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
when('/',{
    templateUrl: '/static/ag_template/apiList.html',
    controller:'MainController'
});
}]);

 AngularApp.controller('MainController',['$scope','ApiListFactory', function($scope,ApiListFactory){
var hi=ApiListFactory.query();
console.log(hi);

 }]);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. is this the correct way to send post data by using $resource ?
2. what am i doing wrong for getting the above error ?

Your help is really appreciable....

Comment: It's a CORS issue. Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @BKM:   Do You mean server-side problem ? According to my knowledge server-side is good....i am thinking about client-side....BTW, is that the correct way to post the data by using $resource...

Comment: Ya the way you're posting data is fine. It's the cross domain issue.